# Flask to autobahn and twisted: RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Tags: flask, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I would like to send session data from the Flask part to the Websocket part of my app. A simplified example is:

```
from flask import session

class EchoServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.user= session.get('user')

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        _user=self.user

        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary, _user)

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

@app.route('/')
def page_home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

(adapted from [here](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi/server.py)).

I received the error:

```
File "app.py", line 171, in __init__
    if session.get('user'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
exceptions.RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Autobahn, but the Flask `session` object is somewhat magic and is only available when *Flask* is handling a request (or when a Flask request context is active).  In the code you linked, Autobahn is handling the web sockets separately from Flask, which is handling the regular requests.  You could try using Flask-Sockets or Flask-SocketIO to make Flask aware of the web sockets.

Comment: in the posted example, the EchoServerProtocol is reached through index.html, so it is not completely separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary solution I found was to save the user name as a pickle object in the Flask part, and to load the pickle object in the websocket part, like:

```
from flask import session
import pickle

class EchoServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.user=  pickle.load(open('../static/uploads/userfile.p', 'rb'))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        _user=self.user

        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary, _user)

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

@app.route('/')
def page_home():
    _user=session.get('user')

    pickle.dump(_user, open('../static/uploads/userfile.p', 'wb'))

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: I don't know, I am mostly afraid that this approach won't scale to a server with many users. I am using a single file 'userfile.p' for everyone, hoping that 2 different users won't access the same file at the same time.

Comment: Have you considered Klein or Tornado? With Klein you can use Autobahn very easily and Tornado has a simple web socket module too. As you know, Flask does alot of magic behind the scenes which makes it a bit difficult to program at times, websockets being one of those areas of difficulty.

Comment: I will probably re-write everything in Tornado next time, but now I already started in Flask. Twisted (the webserver used in the example) also has a 'session' object, that I can consider.